# runc: "start" requires a minimum of 1 argument

Tags: runc

I followed this [runc tutorial](https://www.katacoda.com/lalyos/scenarios/runc) and then sought to replicate it on my own machine.

The final command is 'sudo runc start' when in a directory with a config.json and rootfs directory.

Works fine in the tutorial, however on my machine I get the error **runc: "start" requires a minimum of 1 argument**

Anyone know how to resolve?

Comment: Please consider accepting the given answer if it solved your problem, so that it can be seen that this question has an answer in the question list.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a name for the container. Also note that recently the UX for runC changed. You'll want to do this:

```
% runc run container-name
```

Or to use the create-start split commands:

```
% runc create container-name # Creates the container.
% runc start container-name # Starts the container process.
```